# How can I test func with params that return a object?

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs

I want to test a function that returns a object with given parameters. How can I test it ?
Func.js

```
const functions = {
  createUserWithParams: (firstname, lastname) => ({
    firstname,
    lastname
  })
}

export default functions;
```

func-test.js

```
test('should be create a user with params', () => {
  expect(functions.createUserWithParams()).toStrictEqual({firstName: 'John', lastname: 'Travery'})
});
```

I know the test is wrong, How can I test it successfully ?

Answer (score 0):

functions is an object. so you'll need to use key createUserWithParams to access the function definition in your test and don't forget to pass the parameters

```js
test('should be create a user with params', () => {
  expect(functions['createUserWithParams']('John', 'Travery')).toStrictEqual({firstName: 'John', lastname: 'Travery'})
});

test('should be create a user with params', () => {
  expect(functions.createUserWithParams('John', 'Travery')).toStrictEqual({firstName: 'John', lastname: 'Travery'})
});
```